# difference Open-shift advance and quick installation

Tags: openshift

I am new to Openshift world. When I try to setup Openshift cluster (I tried mini-shift already), I got two main styles (or ways) to setup open-shift. 
1. Advanced installation
2. Quick installation

As the name suggests I think in advance installation we can get more control on installation, but quick installation is interactive but less controlled installation.

I googled out but I did not get any link for pros and cons for each of this type. I did not understand which way I can choose when. Can somebody help me out?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set up single-node development cluster, use `minishift` as you have already tried.

If you want to deploy any other cluster, do the `Advanced` installation. It's good for single-node clusters as well as production-grade multi-node deployments.

I usually do not recommend users to do the `Quick` installation, unless you a very specific reason to require this method.

Comment: that's not understood, what is the specific reason. What are pros and cons of advanced and quick installation?